# Демон на ubuntu 22.04 при самостоятельном запуске файла питон не видит telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, telegram-bot, daemon

В ubuntu 22.04 написал сервис для перезапуска телеграмм бота на питоне, в случае падения. Если запускаю командой python3 /home/bnn/Exchange_bot_private , то файл работает. Но если через написаный сервис, пишет, что модуля telebot нет

```
[Unit] 
Description=Telegram bot

After=network.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/Exchange_bot_private/exchange_bot.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

когда запускаю команды

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start telegram-bot.service
sudo systemctl status telegram-bot.service
```

то статус выдаёт

```
× telegram-bot.service - Telegram bot
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/telegram-bot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-05-24 11:41:58 UTC; 6s ago
    Process: 51783 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/Exchange_bot_private/exchange_bot.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 51783 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 94ms

May 24 11:41:58 bnn-vm systemd[1]: Started Telegram bot.
May 24 11:41:58 bnn-vm python3[51783]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 24 11:41:58 bnn-vm python3[51783]:   File "/home/Exchange_bot_private/exchange_bot.py", line 1, in <module>
May 24 11:41:58 bnn-vm python3[51783]:     import telebot
May 24 11:41:58 bnn-vm python3[51783]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
May 24 11:41:58 bnn-vm systemd[1]: telegram-bot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 24 11:41:58 bnn-vm systemd[1]: telegram-bot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Почему не видит telebot, хотя он есть, и обычным способом запускается

Comment: Что такое «обычным способом»?

Comment: Вангую, что python установлен "для пользователей", т.е. все библиотеки установленные идут в `/usr` или куда там, не помню уже. А при запуске от системного аккаунта все эти библиотеки не видны. Как вариант в самом коде Python можно указать полный путь до библиотеки при импорте. [Вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135273/8489602).

Comment: @andreymal имеется ввиду просто через терминал ввести python3 и имя файла

Comment: Окей, а как и куда telebot установлен?

Comment: @andreymal сюда /home/bnn/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages

Comment: В службе вы не прописали запуск от имени пользователя bnn, а значит по умолчанию идёт запуск от имени root, в котором никакого телебота нет

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, поменял запуск от имени, и теперь работает, всё было так просто